# when will it be possible to access the camera, accelerometer, gps using html5

Tags: html, titanium

I use now appcelerator because it gives me access to this functionalities while still allowing a cross-platform development. But when do you think it will we possible to do this things using HTML5? Do you think that would be the end of titanium?

Comment: @Al-Mothafar The HTML spec is developed by the 'Web Hypertext *Application* Technology Working Group (WHATWG)', so it's already happened.

Comment: @robertc Yes, right, but just I commented as what I understood, HTML5 without any "adds" , like <camera> tag for using camera not with embed code or using Java Applets, sorry if my English not help for understand what I meant :) 

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://www.albertosarullo.com/blog/javascript-accelerometer-demo-source), Safari Mobile supports **accelerometer** access through Javascript starting with iOS 4.2. There is also [a demo](http://www.albertosarullo.com/demos/accelerometer/) (requiring Safari Mobile) included in the blog post.

**GPS** can be accessed through the [Geolocation API](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html) in Javascript, which is supported by most modern browsers, but will obviously only work on devices with some sort of geolocation.

As for the **camera**, I believe PhoneGap handles this, but that is probably through native hooks of some sort.

While that doesn't definitively answer your question, hopefully it points you in the right direction!

Comment: @robertc Nice...it will be interesting to see how that plays out as more browsers/devices start supporting it.